# Store token and user Id for resetting password

Tags: php, codeigniter, token

When someone clicks on forget password I am calling this function now.

```
 public function reset_password($token){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[100]|valid_email|xxs_clean');
       //if email is not right through them back
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('forgot_password_view');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }else{
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            // Verify the username is not in use already.
            $userid = $this->myajax->getUserByAuth($token);
            $result = $this->user_profile->IsUsernameInUse($email, $userid);
            $data = array(
                'userid' => $userid,
                'token' => $token,
                'expiration' => date('Y-m-d')

            );
            $this->db->insert('reset_password', $data);
            //$this->send_reset_password_email($email, $result);
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('reset_password_sent_view', array('email'=> $email));
            $this->load->view('footer');


        }
    }
```

My problem is that the token is expired, because a new token is generated for the user. A new token is generated  every time an ordinary www call is made. I need a way to change logic and save the token that I  will send the user via email in a new support table alongside with the user's ID and the expiration time stamp for the token, and the expiration time stamp I am not sure how to add 15 minutes more.

This are the errors I get.
[image]

Comment: is it your controller or any custom function ?

Comment: if your token generate later sometimes you can use `public function reset_password($token = null ){` and add token value if you will get `null`.

Comment: have you get user_id  by calling this function  $userid = $this->myajax->getUserByAuth($token); and authorized by token ?

Comment: @AmitChauhan I got userid as 171 which is correct with that function , which I guess means that its authorized by token

Comment: @Yash if token is null, how can I store it in my database and I need to send the users by email later on so they can change their password

Comment: @PHPExpert the function you see is part of a controller called login

Comment: @Farhana if token is null you can generate new token at same time than save it to your database and send to user via email.

Comment: @Yash and even if I do make it null, my database wont be able to store it, since I restricted database to store not null

Comment: @Yash can you tell me how to do it? do I use the $token = null ?

Comment: @Yash I used token = null and all errors go away besides the database error

Comment: @Farhana First you can get userid via user email if token = null  found. than generate and save new token for same user and send to user via mail.

Comment: @Yash How can I generate a new token ?? in that place

Comment: Earlier how you generated ..?

Comment: @Yash in a view file, in the header like this 
<script>
            <?php
                $ci =&get_instance(); 
                echo "var auth = \"". $ci->myajax->getCurrentAuth() ."\";";

Comment: so can't you use `$ci->myajax->getCurrentAuth()` for token generation ..?

Comment: I wrote it like this 
$ci->myajax->getCurrentAuth();
 $userid = $this->myajax->getUserByAuth($token);
@Yash is it right ?

Comment: @Farhana Write `$ci =&get_instance();  $token =  $ci->myajax->getCurrentAuth();` than rest are fine.

Comment: @Yash Thanks alot ! it works, do you know how to get the expirationdate for the token, right now i have a date , but I need a timestamp or something which needs to be + 20 mins